VS Code 'Go to Definition' Not Working for Methods in Async Fixtures for Playwright Tests
I am experiencing an issue with Visual Studio Code (VS Code) where the 'Go to Definition' feature is not functioning for methods defined in async fixtures for Playwright tests. Here’s a summary of the problem:
Code Setup

fixture2.js

import { test as baseTest } from "@playwright/test";
import { HomePage2 } from "../homePage2";

export const test2 = baseTest.extend({
  homePage2: async ({ page }, use) => {
    const homePage2 = new HomePage2();
    await use(homePage2);
  }
});


homePage2.js:

export class HomePage2 {
  async simpleMethod() {
    console.log("Simple method called");
  }
}


homePage2.spec.js:

import { test2 } from "../pages/fixtures/fixture2";

test2("Click to System Administration button", async ({ homePage2 }) => {
  await homePage2.simpleMethod();
});

Problem:
In the setup above, when using the async fixture method in fixture2.js, the 'Go to Definition' feature in VS Code does not navigate to the simpleMethod in HomePage2. Instead, it displays "No definition found". However, if I define homePage2 directly without using async (commented out in the code), 'Go to Definition' works as expected.
What I’ve Tried:
Ensured that HomePage2 and its methods are properly defined and exported.
Verified that all relevant files are included in the VS Code workspace.
Added a jsconfig.json with appropriate configuration.
Updated VS Code and its extensions to the latest versions.
Recreated the .vscode directory.
Question:
What steps can I take to fix the issue where 'Go to Definition' does not work for methods in async fixtures in VS Code? Are there specific configurations or troubleshooting steps that might help resolve this issue?

Does your code, inside simpleMethod(), have only the console.log or any promise-returning action ? And your fixture seems to be not correct -> ref . Your fixture does not have a type -> extend<{homePage2: HomePage2}>....

It is only example with console.log. I posted it here for the better understanding.
Your fixture does not have a type -> extend<{homePage2: HomePage2}> => we need to have type for Type Script, but I use Java script.

Then I don´t understand why your imports are TypeScript style and the extend in JavaScript style. https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-test#test-extend

These imports are also correct for javascript
